# Facing a problem in JavaScript on Brackets

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

When I write: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` on Brackets editor I face a problem, it says: `ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]`.
Thank you...

Comment: That's coming from ESLint: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef. You need to tell the editor you expect that code to run in a browser environment.

Comment: BTW: this has nothing to do with the `brackets` tag. Read the usage description, ... especially the part in CAPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If so you can change your **eslint** config by using environment "browser" to ignore those error.

The Document method `getElementById()` returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified, they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.

If you need to get access to an element:

```
let element = document.getElementById("demo")

element.innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

Comment: I found a solution for the problem, it is:                                                                              Write a multi line comment in the top page /*global (Element) for example /*global document, prompt, alert, */ bla bla....